# if and && concept in shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to Shell script , I am trying to run a simple code

Input for the test.sh file will be input1 and input2 (For Example ./test_script.sh input1 input2)

```
#!/bin/bash
export a=$1
export b=$2
if ["$a" -eq ''] && ["$b" -eq '']
then
echo "Please enter an input"
elif ["$a"] && ["$b" -eq '']
then
echo "the value of a is $a"
elif ["$a"] && ["$b"]
then
echo "The value of a is $a and b is $b"
else
print "Something went wrong "

fi
```

Is this syntax correct because I am getting an error , Need help to find where I am going wrong

```
 ./test.sh 10 11
 ./test.sh: line 5: [10: command not found
 ./test.sh: line 10: [10]: command not found
 ./test.sh: line 14: [10]: command not found
 ./test.sh: line 19: print: command not found
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)
and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Comment: spaces matter!!!